# Common Mode Noise on Differential Lines Driven Against Chassis GND

Tags: inductor, differential, common-mode-choke

How is common mode noise filtered on differential lines that have a noise source that is driving them relative to chassis GND? I drew a picture of what I am imagining below. Imagine a PCB with differential signals that are in a metal enclosure.

[image]

I think the common mode noise will drive the entire circuit with a current shown in purple below:

[image]

All the documentation I find show single ended examples like the one in reference image 1 below, where a choke is used between the signal line and system GND to reject the common mode. There are also examples like reference image 2 below where a choke is used to reject common mode between two differential lines (say from a skew mismatch of the transmission lines).

To deal with this do I need to use 3 common mode chokes? One between the two differential signals, and then on each differential signal and ground? Advice is appreciated.

Choke 1: N and P signal

Choke 2: N signal and system GND

Choke 3: P signal and system GND

REFERENCE IMAGE 1: Choke on single-ended signal and system GND. 
[image]
Image [Source](https://www.powerelectronictips.com/power-supply-noise-part-2/)

REFERENCE IMAGE 2: Choke on differential signals.

[image]
Image [Source](https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/emc/emifil/knowhow/basic/chapter05-p1)

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to filter the noise? EMC reasons?

Comment: Yes, EMC reasons. This is not a problem that has occurred but came up in hypothetical discussions with colleagues.@KevinWhite

Comment: What is the pink vertical line in the middle?

Comment: Wouldn't the CM just short across the circuit through system ground? If it doesn't that seems like it's a really bad system ground which would mean that the first things to do before adding a choke would be to lower the impedance of the system ground and also connecting system ground to chassis ground before a choke is added.

Comment: @DKNguyen. Pink vertical line is the CM current. What you are saying would not work. Even if it went only though ground you've created a loop antenna. The current will not go only through system ground but will split between all possible paths based on impedence.

Comment: @Gonzik007 Oh, the pink vertical line is covering up a line in the top diagram that I missed. "The current will not go only through system ground but will split between all possible paths based on impedence." Yes, so the question is why did you make system ground such a high impedance that not only does significant common mode currents split off into the system and also produces significant significant emissions as they circulate?

Comment: @DKNguyen....in the design the system GND is not high impedance. You still create a loop antenna between chassis GND and system GND if the GND is low impedance, which could cause a compliance failure.

Comment: @Gonzik007 I'm looking at Chapter 3 in Henry Ott's EMC book and everything I see tells me that this is a problem with the system ground impedance, not something that is being caused by a lack of common mode chokes.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen multiple common mode chokes used as you describe.

The systems I've been involved with have normally used a double common mode choke with one in each of P and N (none in the ground). This would be used for USB or similar signals (e.g. MIPI-CSI)

In some cases a triple common mode choke with three windings on the same core was used. That was in a cell-phone. I can't currently find a reference to it. I wasn't the EMC engineer so I don't have any details.